# How to display search results in a table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am busy with a simple html/php script and all I want to do is display the results I search for from my database in a table form but nothing is showing.
Here is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>product sales for a specific customer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <h3 align="center"> Please Search for a specific customer you want to see sales for: </h3>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="txtNameSearch" />
            <input class="src_btn" type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" />
                <table width="800" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                <th>Order Details Id</th>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Product Id</th>
                <th>Login ID</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Product Price per unit</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Product Descrp</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity Sold</th>
                </tr> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST["btnSearch"]))
{
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bookstore');
$sql="SELECT * FROM order_details right join tblproduct on order_details.prod_id=tblproduct.prod_id WHERE id_login = $search";
$Joined_records=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if (isset($_POST['txtNameSearch'])){
    $search = $_POST['txtNameSearch'];
}
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Joined_records)){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$row["order_details_id"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["order_id"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_id"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["id_login"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["quantity"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["price_per_unit"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_name"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_descr"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_cat"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_price"]."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$row["prod_quan"]."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";

}
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is for instance I type "3" in the search bar and I click submit I want all the values corresponding with that 3 in my database to display in a table form.

Comment: You're running your query, which is vulnerable to SQL injection BTW, before you get the search value from POST.

Comment: @MattS I tried that but it still doesn't work

Comment: @MoeJoe What Matt is saying is that you're assigning a value to your `$search` variable after you've finished searching the database. Do it the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your code:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
  FROM order_details 
  right join tblproduct 
  on order_details.prod_id=tblproduct.prod_id 
  WHERE id_login = $search";
```

Leaving aside the problems with this SQL, you have not defined `$search` until later in the code. This needs to be done **before** you create your query string containing the embedded vault, and it **must** be properly escaped and must be quoted in the query:

```
$search = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string(
       $connection, $_POST['txtNameSearch']
       ) . "'";
```

You should also add proper error checking and handling to (at least) the mysqli_query() call.